# Facebook Group Navigation bar disappeared? Can't find group albums anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

In every other group I'm in there is a navigation bar to link to announcements, media, files, etc. where we would normally find the link to view all of the albums created in the group. Recently though the navigation bar just completely disappeared. When posting photos, we can still add photos to the album but the only way to see the albums are through the main feed of the group. We have saved links to the page with all of the albums that previously worked but no longer do. Is there any way to get it back or find the new page with the albums? I can't find any way to and other groups I'm in all still have the navigation bar.